# Automatically generating JSON script files from file name

Tags: json

I'd like to use a JSON file as a template to create new JSON files with a couple of words in the script that change according to the file name.

For example, say I have a JSON file called word1.json, with a script looking like this:

filename: word1.json

script:

```
{
  "name": "word1",
  "annotates": "word1.wav",
  "sampleRate": 44100
}
```

I want to automatically generate a new JSON script for every file name I enter, for example:

filename: word2.json

script:

```
{
  "name": "word2",
  "annotates": "word2.wav",
  "sampleRate": 44100
}
```

filename: newword.json

script:

```
{
  "name": "newword",
  "annotates": "newword.wav",
  "sampleRate": 44100
}
```

and so on.

Is there some software that allows me to do it? I'm currently editing the JSON files with TextEdit - I'm not a programmer as you can probably tell, but I can use R and can do a little bit of programming there.

EDIT: I'm on MacOS

Many thanks.

Comment: How many files is it about. I'm not saying it cannot be done programmatically, but wouldn't it be easier to use the search-and-replace function of the text editor?

Comment: @Noam that's the thing, there are hundreds of files (I'm doing this for my research at university). I wanted to avoid manually creating the new files.

Comment: I'd recommend a programmer for this. This site is good for programmers needing assistance, not for others to write a program for you. Is there anything you have tried to solve this issue? As in, have you tried any programming at all to solve for this?

Comment: @Esaith I'm not expecting someone to write a program for me - I'm looking for indications as to what programming software I could use to solve this issue. I can use R if that helps.

Comment: Any programming language that can read and write files and do basic string manipulation. Python, Ruby, Node JS, etc. Probably R too but I have no knowledge of it.

Comment: @Noam OK thanks I'll try with R as it's the only one I have some knowledge of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll probably get some hate here, but since you are new, you are not a programmer, and it's a simple request I say 'Everybody gets one'.

This is a C# program that can be run in any compatible IDE. If you do not have one installed, you can run using LinqPad. It's a quick and simple installation. Open LinqPad and run as C# Program. Press the Play button start the program.

You will need to add the NuGet "Newtonsoft.Json".

This program will create a new directory on your hard drive at C:\jsonfiles. It will repeatedly ask you to enter in a file name until you enter in 'exit' at which point the program will exit. Rerun as needed.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("JSON Creator");
    Console.WriteLine("For each entered file name a JSON file will be created. The files will be created at C:/jsonfiles. If the file already exists it will be overwritten.");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter 'exit' to end the program");

    string jsonDirectory = @"C:\jsonfiles";
    CreateBaseDirectory(jsonDirectory);

    string jsonFileName = GetUserInput();

    while (QuitProgram(jsonFileName) == false)
    {
        string fullJsonPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(jsonDirectory, jsonFileName + ".json");

        try
        {
            DeleteExistingFile(fullJsonPath);
        }
        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to delete file. The file may be in use. Please close the file or manually delete the file before continuing on.");
            jsonFileName = GetUserInput();
            continue;
        }

        try
        {
            SaveToFile(jsonFileName, fullJsonPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There was an issue creating the file. Verify the file does not already exist, the file name is valid, the file is not open, and you have privileges to write to the file system");
            jsonFileName = GetUserInput();
            continue;
        }

        jsonFileName = GetUserInput();
    }

}

private void CreateBaseDirectory(string jsonDirectory)
{
    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(jsonDirectory) == false)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(jsonDirectory);
    }
}

private bool InputIsValid(string input)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) == false;
}

private bool QuitProgram(string input)
{
    string modifiedInput = input?.Trim()?.ToLower();
    return modifiedInput == "quit" || modifiedInput == "q" || modifiedInput == "exit";
}

private string GetUserInput()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter in the JSON file name");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    while (InputIsValid(input) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid JSON file name. An empty or space-only file name is not valid.");
    }

    return input.Trim().Replace(".json", "");
}

private void DeleteExistingFile(string fullJsonPath)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullJsonPath))
    {
        File.Delete(fullJsonPath);
    }
}

private void SaveToFile(string jsonFileName, string fullJsonPath)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    JsonTemplate template = new JsonTemplate();
    template.name = jsonFileName;
    template.annotates = jsonFileName + ".wav";

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullJsonPath, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template));
    Console.WriteLine(jsonFileName + " has been created");
}

private class JsonTemplate
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string annotates { get; set; }
    public int sampleRate { get; set; } = 44100;
}
```

*Edit*

I just noticed that you are on MacOS. I do not have access nor much knowledge on programming through MacOS. At minimum, you will need to update the location as to where the directory is saved.